# How to update 'status' value in table on each button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to update the `status` value in the `properties` table as (1 or 2 or 3 or 4) when I click on each button.

These are my buttons in my view file:

```
<td><%= link_to("Waiting for Response", rms_property_approve_property_path(property, {:status => 'Waiting for Response'}), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-success", "data-no-turbolink" => true) %><td>
<td><%= link_to("No Response", rms_property_approve_property_path(property, {:status => 'No Response'}), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-danger", "data-no-turbolink" => true) %><td>
<td><%= link_to("Registered", rms_property_approve_property_path(property, {:status => 'Registered'}), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-success", "data-no-turbolink" => true) %><td>
<td><%= link_to("Not Interested", rms_property_approve_property_path(property, {:status => 'Not Interested'}), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-danger", "data-no-turbolink" => true) %><td>
```

My `properties_controller.rb`:

```
  def approve
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    if params[:status]== 'Registered'
       @property.update_attributes(:status => 1)
       redirect_to :back, flash: {notice: "Property has been Registered."}
    elsif params[:status]== 'Not Interested'
       @property.update_attributes(:status => 2)
       redirect_to :back, flash: {notice: "Not Interested."}
    elsif params[:status]== 'Waiting for Response'
       @property.update_attributes(:status => 3)
       redirect_to :back, flash: {notice: "Waiting for Response"}
    elsif params[:status]== 'No Response'
       @property.update_attributes(:status => 4)
       redirect_to :back, flash: {notice: "No Response."}
    end
  end
```

My migration file for status column in `properties` table:

```
class AddColumnStatusInProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     add_column :properties, :status, :string
  end
end
```

When I click on the `No response` button, I get an ArgumentError:

```
'4' is not a valid status
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by the error message, it seems that you are using an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) on the `status` column. You can't use **raw values** (the integer part of the enum value) with enums unless you skip object instantiation (using [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), or [`update_columns`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns), for example).

If you instantiate the object, you must use the enum value (value is `:registered`, while raw value is `1`).

In `approve`, you need to update the object as such:

```
# `:registered` should be the enum value, not the number
@property.update_attributes(status: :registered)
```

And not

```
@property.update_attributes(status: 4)
```

This assumes you have declared your enum as such:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: {
    registered: 1,
    not_interested: 2,
    waiting_for_response: 3, # consider renaming to `awaiting_response`
    registered: 4
  }
end
```

You should change the column type in the migration to `integer`. Using string can lead to strange bugs.

```
rails g migration change_status_column_type_in_properties

class ChangeStatusColumnTypeInProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     change_column :properties, :status, :integer
  end
end
```

You can also automate the link generation in your view:

```
<% Property.statuses.each_key do |name| %>
  <%= link_to name, rms_property_approve_property_path(property, {status: name}), method: :patch, class: "btn btn-danger", "data-no-turbolink" => true) %>
<% end %>
```

And simplify the controller code:

```
def approve
  @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  @property.update!(status: params[:status])
  redirect_to :back, notice: t(".#{params[:status]}")
end
```

And add the flash messages to your locale file. For example:

```
en:
  rms:
    properties:
      approve:
        registered: "Property registered"
        waiting_for_response: "..."
```

Finally, consider using a default value to your column.

```
change_column :properties, :status, :integer, null: false, default: 3
```

Comment: it is working fine. thanks for correcting my mistake, also thanks for such a detailed answer . thanks a lot @Mohamad