# rails method undefined job_apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get and error undefined method 'job_apps' (tried with single form 'job_app' too)

```
def accept 
        @job_apps = job_apps.find(params[:id])
        @job_apps.update_attribute(status: :accept)
end
def refuse
        @job_apps = job_apps.find(params[:id])
        @job_apps.update_attribute(:status,2)
end

routes:

get 'accept' => 'job_apps#accept'
post 'accept' => 'job_apps#accept'
```

Tried:

```
def accept 
        @job_apps = @user.job_app
        @job_apps.update_attribute(status: :accept)
    end
```

I had similar trouble for calling the job_app in the same view (to see job_app.status as it is table joined with users on user_id) but on stack overflow someone helped me with this (view file):

```
<th><%= user.job_app.status %></th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method 'job_apps'

This `@job_apps = job_apps.find(params[:id])` is wrong. You need to use the ***classname*** when writing a ***ActiveRecord*** query. Th below should work

```
@job_apps = JobApp.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: thank you! but now, the ruby cant find JobApp by params[:id]

Comment: @Amit solved it, but now i have this: Missing template job_apps/accept, application/accept in routes:  get 'accept.:id' => 'job_apps#accept'
 post 'accept.:id' => 'job_apps#accept'

Comment: It is b'coz no template present for render , write `redirect_to action: "index"` at the end of 'accept' action to redirect to index page.